# C# asp.net WebForm add JS and run it from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this `WebForm` `Html`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GetLink.aspx.cs" Inherits="GetLink" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnVal" value="55"/>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And i want to add to this code a `JavaScript` function and run it with this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("key1"))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key1", @"<script type=""text/javascript"">function callMyJSFunction() { document.getElementById(""hdnVal"").value='5'; }</script>");
        }

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key1", "<script>callMyJSFunction();</script>");

        string resutOfExecuteJavaScript = hdnVal.Value;
    }
```

When i run it the value of `hdnVal` keep the `55` value and not change. Any  idea what is the problem?

Comment: Study [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2) page carefully and everything you need is there. Pay special attention to the part about registering scripts with the same key multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in Page_Load event should call `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` when registering the JavaScript function of *callMyJSFunction*, whereas in your code you are registering this function as a startup script. This is the only mistake in your code.

So, if you change your server-side code to as below, then it will work according to your expectations.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("key1"))
    {
        //register your javascript function
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "key1", @"<script type=""text/javascript"">function callMyJSFunction() { document.getElementById(""hdnVal"").value='5'; }</script>");
    }

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key1", "<script>callMyJSFunction();</script>");

    string resutOfExecuteJavaScript = hdnVal.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is you are creating function in Clientscript while you can simply put the function in javascript and then just do the calling part.Second problem is that the time your function is calling that hiddenfield for view its not available on document simply means stop putting your code on page load and use a button click event instead.Third problem is you are using multiple inverted commas at so many places which aren't required.

This worked for me

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $('document').ready()
      {
          function callMyJSFunction()
          {
              debugger;
              document.getElementById('hdnVal').value = '5';
 alert(document.getElementById('hdnVal').value);
          }
          // - including fonts, images, etc.
      }
   </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnVal" value="55"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and on cs page

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key1", "<script>callMyJSFunction()</script>",false);

        string resutOfExecuteJavaScript = hdnVal.Value;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can check out my answer that I have just posted. You are calling the wrong method when registering the JavaScript function, that I have explained in my answer.